# Handling Single Array Values

Tags: php, arrays

*This is using WordPress lingo - but is more of a core PHP based question.* I have an option in my site backend that I am storing a specific Location (a WordPress custom post type) as the "headquarters". I am storing the value as such:

```
function options_headquarters() {
    foreach(get_field('option_headquarters','options') as $post_object) {
        $options_headquarters = $post_object->ID;
        return $options_headquarters;
    }
}
```

What I am fuzzy on is - since my option is only allowed to grab one value (option is configured to just be a single dropdown) -- is there an alternative to using a foreach statement (to grab just a specific array value) and still applying it to the post_object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function options_headquarters() {
  $options = get_field('option_headquarters','options');
  $options_hq = isset($options[0]) ? $options[0]->ID : NULL;
  return $options_hq;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Just one quick follow up question (I just read that you're not a usual WP user - so let me know if I should reference elsewhere for this) -- I see that you're assigning the `options[0]->ID` how is that referencing the `$post_object->ID`? I'm just trying to think this through. I changed one of the lines to be `$options_hq = $options[0];` and it actually worked (not going into any type of `ID` table So maybe it's just that the actual `get_field()` function already returns that number and I don't need anything else, but should I check for a value first? I think I just confused myself ;)

Comment: The `get_field('option_headquarters','options')` returns an array, so your original code is simply looping over that array with a `foreach`. The `$options[0]` is forgoing the loop and saying, "I want the first element in the returned array" ... the "0" key is the first in a numerically indexed array. The reason I used `isset($options[0])` is for the off chance that `get_field` returned an empty array (because no value existed for that field in the database) or if `get_field` returned a value that wasn't an array. If either of these happen, `isset` prevents PHP from throwing a warning or notice

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation. Will definitely take a look at @Felix Kling's way as well. I purchased the book "Code Complete" now let's put it to good use! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just get the array and access the first element:

```
$post_object = array_pop(get_field('option_headquarters','options'));
```

**Reference**: [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: +1 Very clean. The only thing to think about is you could get a PHP warning if the Wordpress `get_field` function doesn't return an array if no values are found. I don't know how the WP internal stuff works ...

Comment: The documentation says *If array is empty (or is not an array), NULL will be returned.*, so I think it should be fine, even if no array is returned. Of course one would have to test `$post_object` then. But I don't have any insight in the WP API either.

Comment: From the array_pop docs: *Will additionally produce a Warning when called on a non-array.*

Comment: Haha no worries I'm the worst about that. Good for about one downvote per day because I can't be bothered to read all the way to the end :)